# Cannot Connect to Public Tableau

Tags: connection, tableau-api

Intermittent connection Public Tableau since yesterday morning.

Other forums recommend making changes to IE9, i.e.

`Tools -> Internet Options > Advanced > Security Section > 
Uncheck Check for publicher's certificate revocation 
AND 
Uncheck Check for server certificate revocation`

I restarted machine, and problem persists. How to troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: When you click on `Show Details` what is the information that is provided?

Comment: @Nicarus `Your connection has probably timed out. Try to reconnect to Tableau Server.`

Comment: @Nicarus `Service Unavailable. Check to make sure the service is running.`

Comment: Have you tried again since that time? Maybe Tableau Public was down. I remember that it once happened to me.

Comment: @epo3 I will try again.